# googleapis "The request is missing a valid API key" with bash

Tags: google-api

If I paste the url below into a browser like chrome o mozilla (tested in both) works fine. A json is returned.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLWCXX8tjkPYsRRdiiNdPlWFD0Pd0eQgsQ&key=**************

But with curl o wget...

```bash
ubuntu@bast01:~$ curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLWCXX8tjkPYsRRdiiNdPlWFD0Pd0eQgsQ&key=**************
[1] 1769895
[2] 1769896
ubuntu@bast01:~$ {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

[1]-  Done                    curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet
[2]+  Done                    playlistId=PLWCXX8tjkPYsRRdiiNdPlWFD0Pd0eQgsQ
ubuntu@bast01:~$
```

The browser shows me some request headers sended by default.

```
:authority:
www.googleapis.com
:method:
GET
:path:
/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLWCXX8tjkPYsRRdiiNdPlWFD0Pd0eQgsQ&key=AIzaSyAw76LojcMcU64S35LQYUCKMEKx4XuI06I
:scheme:
https
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
es-ES,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control:
max-age=0
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site:
none
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data:
CIW2yQEIpLbJAQipncoBCOvUygEI/vXKAQiSocsBCIurzAEImv7MAQiFk80BCIegzQEI0LHNAQjcvc0BCLy+zQEI4MTNAQjvxM0BCLfIzQEIucrNAQjgys0BCNDLzQEIuM3NARjBy8wB
Decoded:
message ClientVariations {
  // Active client experiment variation IDs.
  repeated int32 variation_id = [3300101, 3300132, 3313321, 3320427, 3324670, 3330194, 3347851, 3358490, 3361157, 3362823, 3365072, 3366620, 3366716, 3367520, 3367535, 3367991, 3368249, 3368288, 3368400, 3368632];
  // Active client experiment variation IDs that trigger server-side behavior.
  repeated int32 trigger_variation_id = [3352001];
}
```

It could be some of these headers? Maybe I need to send some of them?

Comment: I would question where you got your key from.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo from https://console.cloud.google.com/  -> Library.... I wrote two scripts in PHP and Ruby with this very key and are working. I have de solution but I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my is just this....

```bash
playlistId='PLWCXX8tjkPYsRRdiiNdPlWFD0Pd0eQgsQ'
key='********'


youtube=$(/usr/bin/curl -G -s https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems \
     -d part='snippet' \
     -d playlistId=$playlistId \
     -d key=$key | jq -r '.pageInfo.totalResults')
```

But to be honest, I don't understand why my first try does not work.